Two equal symmetric bilinear forms.

Note that the second fundamental form is completely determined by its values of the form $\text{II}(v,v)$ for unit vectors $v$, by the following lemma.
Lemma 8.11 Suppose $V$ is an inner product space, $W$ is a vector space, and $B,B':V \times V \to W$ are symmetric and bilinear. If $B(v,v) = B'(v,v)$ for every unit vector $v \in V$, then $B = B'$.
Proof. Every vector $v \in V$ can be written $v = \lambda \hat v$ [SIC] for some unit vector $\hat v$, so the bilinearity of $B$ and $B'$ implies $B(v,v) = B'(v,v)$ for every $v$, not just unit vectors. The result then follows from the following polarization identity, which is proved in exactly the same way as its counterpart for inner products:
$$
B(v,w) = \tfrac 14 (B(v+w,v+w) - B(v-w,v-w)). \qquad \qquad \square
$$

(image from textbook)
Problem: Suppose $V$ is an inner product space, $W$ vector space and $B,B'$ are symmetric and blinear. If $B(v,v) = B'(v,v)$ for every unit vector then the two bilinear forms are equal $B = B'.$
So I don't know if I am missing interpreting the final result when it says " the result follows from polarization"
Are they saying the polarization identity shows $B(v,w) = B'(v,w)$ for any vector?
So since $B(v,v) = B'(v,v)$ for any unit vector, does this mean it wants us to compare for any  unit vector $\tilde{v},\tilde{w} \in V$, $B(\lambda \tilde{v}, \lambda \tilde{w})$ to $B'(\lambda \tilde{v}, \lambda \tilde{w})$?

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

Yes, they are saying that the polarization identity shows that $B(v,w) = B'(v,w)$ for any vectors $v, w \in V$ (not just unit vectors).
The point of the first sentence is that for every vector $v \in V$ (not just unit vectors), we have $B(v,v) = B'(v,v)$. To see this, note that if we write $v = \lambda \hat v$ as the proof suggests, we find that
\begin{align}
B(v,v) &= 
B(\lambda \hat v, \lambda \hat v) 
\\ & = \lambda^2 B(\hat v, \hat v)
\\ & = \lambda^2 B'(\hat v, \hat v) 
\\ & = B'(\lambda \hat v, \lambda \hat v) = B'(v,v).
\end{align}
Now that we have established that $B(v,v) = B'(v,v)$, we can make use of the polarization identity by noting that $B(v + w, v + w) = B'(v + w, v + w)$ and $B(v-w, v -w) = B'(v -w, v-w)$.
That is, we can write
\begin{align}
B(v,w) &= \tfrac 14 (B(v+w,v+w) - B(v-w,v-w))
\\ & = \tfrac 14 (B'(v+w,v+w) - B'(v-w,v-w)) = B'(v,w).
\end{align}

Okay so I reached the first part $B(v,v) = B'(v,v)$ as well, but when you expand $B(w+v, w+v) = B(v,v) + B(w,w) + B(v,w) + B(w,v) = B'(v,v) + B'(w,w) + 2B(v,w).$ Then we can reapply the previous result regarding $B(v,v) = B'(v,v)$ to $2B(v,w) = 2B'(v,w)$ whenever $w,v$ are unit vectors? Is that what is going on? Then this establishes $B(v+w,v+w) = B'(v+w, v+w)$?

The only reason you would need to expand $B(v+w,v+w)$ is if you want to prove the polarization identity that they've given you. Is that what you're trying to do here?

@Con No, we cannot (directly) apply the result about $B(v,v)$ to $B(v,w)$. The entire point of the polarization identity is to be able to say something about $B(v,w)$ using only expressions of the form $B(x,x)$ for some $x \in V$.

Oh okay I see where it went wrong. I am replacing $(v,v)$ by $(v+w, v+w).$ I didn't need to expand anything. This establishes the equality the author is talking about.

@Con That's right. You might find expanding $\tfrac 14 (B(v+w,v+w) - B(v-w,v-w))$ (and seeing that you really get $B(v,w)$) to be a useful exercise, but going from $B$ to $B'$ relies on the fact that all terms are of the form $B(x,x)$ for some $x$.

Is there a reason why we are checking unit vectors if the result holds for any vector when comparing bilinear forms? Are unit vectors easier to check or something?

@Con I can't tell you for sure without more context, but probably yes: either it's easier or it's more convenient to show that $B(v,v) = B(v',v')$ holds only for unit vectors than it is to show for all vectors $v \in V$. For one thing, sticking to unit vectors means you don't have to deal with the $v = 0$ case separately.
